# RDP connect to server with signatured .rdp file

Tags: 20.04, rdp, remmina

I try to connect to an RDP server using a .rdp file.
The file contains a signature and it should allow me to connect without username and password which I did not receive by the company.

I tried to connect using `Remmina` (.deb and recent Flatpak) and `xfreerdp` both does not work. I even tried to install the MS program with `bottles` but without any success.

This is the Remmina protocol:

```
(DEBUG) - (rcw_map_event) - Mapping: RemminaConnectionWindow
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_map_event) - Calling plugin mapping function
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Opening connection
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Disable smooth scrolling is set to 0
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_event_init) - Adding GDK_SMOOTH_SCROLL_MASK
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_open_connection_real) - Have SSH
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - RDP data path is /home/user/.var/app/org.remmina.Remmina/data/remmina/RDP
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Not using system proxy settings
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel init
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - SSH tunnel initialization…
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - Calling remmina_public_get_server_port (tunnel)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_protocol_widget_start_direct_tunnel) - server: SERVERNAME.SERVER.DEE, port: 3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - protocol_plugin_start_direct_tunnel() returned [SERVERNAME.SERVER.DE]:3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_tunnel_init) - Tunnel has been optionally initialized. Now connecting to SERVERNAME.SERVER.DE:3389
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - gfx_h264_available: 1
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set by the user: 592x440
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - Resolution set after workarounds: 592x440
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_type: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_username: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_password: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_hostname: (null)
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - proxy_port: 80
(DEBUG) - (remmina_rdp_main) - rdp_keyboard_remapping_list: (null)
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Disconnect signal received on RemminaProtocolWidget
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Saving profile
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Profile saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_file_save) - Connection profile states saved
(DEBUG) - (remmina_network_monitor_status) - G_NETWORK_CONNECTIVITY_FULL
(DEBUG) - (rco_on_disconnect) - Could not disconnect
```

On the console I get this messages:

```
[20:24:04:751] [128982:129038] [INFO][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Detecting if host can be reached locally. - This might take some time.
[20:24:04:752] [128982:129038] [INFO][com.freerdp.core.nego] - To disable auto detection use /gateway-usage-method:direct
[20:24:04:835] [128982:129038] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - BIO_should_retry returned a system error 32: Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)
[20:24:04:835] [128982:129038] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - transport_write:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_TRANSPORT_FAILED [0x0002000D]
[20:24:04:849] [128982:129038] [INFO][com.freerdp.core.nego] - Detecting if host can be reached locally. - This might take some time.
[20:24:04:849] [128982:129038] [INFO][com.freerdp.core.nego] - To disable auto detection use /gateway-usage-method:direct
[20:24:04:896] [128982:129038] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core.transport] - BIO_should_retry returned a system error 32: Datenübergabe unterbrochen (broken pipe)
[20:24:04:896] [128982:129038] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - transport_write:freerdp_set_last_error_ex ERRCONNECT_CONNECT_TRANSPORT_FAILED [0x0002000D]
[20:24:04:896] [128982:129038] [ERROR][com.freerdp.core] - freerdp_post_connect failed
libfreerdp returned code is 0002000D
```

If I import the .rdp file and then export it the signature `signature:s:` section with the long hashed password is gone.

Is there any chance to establish such a connection within the world of linux?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, I have no insight to the the server side but it’s all Microsoft there.
Any hint helping me solving this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: What OS and version is used on each end?

Comment: "does not work" is a very poor problem description.  Read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: I have the exact same issue. The server is running Windows 2019 Server
The client is Ubuntu 22.04 which has Remmina 1.4 as the default install.
The behavior is that when I import the rdp file and try to connect to the serve, it simply gets to the server which prompts for credentials instead of using the signing information from the file. The curious part is that I have a Ubuntu 17 machine running Remmina 1.2 and that setup works exactly as expected using the signing information from the file allowing me on to the (same) server without any need for username/password.